# when use custom datasource and jpa EntityManager denpendency in root application,throw exception

Tags: spring-boot

when i custom a datasource in my @springbootapplication class and dependency a jpa entitymanager driectly in the same class, like this:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
          return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

it will throw a exception in start process:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

this is also appear when entityManager is indirect to the root application class by Autowired -> Autowired -> Autowired 
but if i move entityManager to another class (Not related to the Application class), such as : in an annotation base bean's property, the problem disappear

by the stack trace, i think it may be a bean dependency  problem here. 
i'm not sure it's a bug or is my mistake. 
i use version of springboot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

[response by him](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12308)

It's your mistake. You're injecting the entity manager as a field into the configuration class. Before the configuration class can create any of the beans that it defines, all of its fields must be injected. This fails because the configuration class that is consuming the entity manager is also providing the data source that is needed to create the entity manager.

In the future, if you think you've made a mistake, please ask a question on Stack Overflow. As mentioned in the guidelines for contributing, we prefer to use GitHub issues only for bugs and enhancements.